# Php error help : mysql_fetch_assoc()

Tags: php

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

my code php is :

```
function getResourceLevel($vid) {
        $q = "SELECT * from " . TB_PREFIX . "fdata where vref = $vid";
        $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
```

Please Help me

Comment: Is your query syntactic correct?

Comment: The short version (where's @truth?): please don't use `mysql_*` functions, it's deprecated (see [*red box*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)) and vulnerable to sql-injection. Use [*PDO*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [*MySQLi*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: As was already stated, your query seems faulty. Try calling mysql_error, when $result returns false, instead of a resource object.

Comment: Looks like you have problems with `$this->connection`

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Comment: @alfasin: Here I am. Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: @alfasin: see http://stackapps.com/q/2116

Comment: @Truth wow!!! that's going to save me a lot of copy & paste... Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [mysql_query()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) has returned *false*.

This could by due to an error in your mysql syntax or due to a lack of permissions for accessing the database table you have requested.

In either case, you can try calling [mysql_error()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) which will return a string with a best guess of what went wrong with your last mysql function.

**Edit**: As mentioned in some of the comments, the use of mysql_* functions is discouraged, so if you have opportunity you should update your code to use the mysqli or PDO MySQL extensions.  Better yet, use something like [Zend DB](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html) to move you one layer further away from the database API.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo your query and run in some mysql query browser and check if its giving required results.

```
function getResourceLevel($vid) {
    $q = "SELECT * from " . TB_PREFIX . "fdata where vref = $vid";
    echo $q;
    $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
    return ($result) ? mysql_fetch_assoc($result) : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getResourceLevel($vid) {
        $q = "SELECT * from " . TB_PREFIX . "fdata where vref = $vid";
        $result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection) || die(mysql_error());
        return mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    }
```

Notice the `|| die(mysql_error())` statement.

This will stop the code and show the sql error that is being returned as false.

Hope this helps.